# kernel cannot execute binaries (error -8)

Tags: linux-kernel, executable, arm, init, cpu-architecture

my platform:

```
SOC = STM32H743 (ARMv7E-M | Cortex-M7)
Board = Waveshare CoreH7XXI 
Linux Kernel = 5.8.10 (stable 2020-09-17)
initial defconfig file = stm32_defconfig
rootfs = built using busybox | busybox compiled using  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

I've created rootfs by following [this guide](https://embedjournal.com/custom-rfs-beaglebone-black/).

my kernel cannot execute any file even the init file >>> `/linuxrc` or `/sbin/init`.

for making sure that the problem is not from busybox files, I wrote a C helloworld program with `-mcpu=cortex-m7` flag and compiled it with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` but again the kernel paniced and throwed the -8 error (Exec format error).

my busybox files are all linked to the busybox binary and the binary is correctly compiled for 32bit arm:

```
$ readelf -A bin/busybox
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "Cortex-M7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7E-M
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

the kernel error:

```
[    0.925859] Run /linuxrc as init process
[    0.943257] Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /linuxrc failed (error -8).
[    0.950654] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /linuxrc failed (error -8). ]---
```

---

my helloworld program:

```
$ readelf -A hello
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7E-M"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7E-M
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

the kernel error:

```
[    1.189550] Run /hello as init process
[    1.198670] Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /hello failed (error -8).
[    1.205977] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /hello failed (error -8). ]---
```

**Why the kernel can't execute binaries?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you are compiling it in a normal static elf format. you should compile it as an FDPIC-ELF executable (because you need a position independent executable (FDPIC) due to the lack of MMU).

FDPIC ELF is not ET_EXEC type. it is ET_DYN (it means it's shared) type and it is loaded by the Linux dynamic loader.

just add a `-mfdpic` flag to it and turn off the *built static binary* in the busybox's kconfig menu.

note that -mfdpic flag is on by default in arm-uclinux-fdpicabi toolchains.