# Linux kernel init, /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)

Tags: kernel, embedded, busybox, kernel-panic

The bug:
Linux kernel boots, load's up initramfs/CPIO image but the init process fails with error -8 (NOEXEC)

```
[    3.499638] Run /init as init process
[    3.506228] Failed to execute /init (error -8)
[    3.510820] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    3.517222] Run /etc/init as init process
[    3.523164] Run /bin/init as init process
[    3.530061] Run /bin/sh as init process
[    3.536048] Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)
[    3.543643] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
```

Used hardware & software:

- STM32F429-discovery board
- Custom kernel and device tree config
- Custom build script from scratch (no buildroot, no yocto, no uclinux)
- Using staticly linked busybox

What I tried:

- Instead of generating CPIO image externally I also tried to specify rootfs/ directory `INITRAMFS_SOURCE=../rootfs/` and let linux makefile build initramfs itself. Also I tried use spec.txt (cat spec.txt below)
- Boot with parameter "noexec=off" ~ `rdinit=/bin/sh console=ttySTM0,115200n8 earlyprintk noexec=off`
- Check if the busybox ELF executable file have correct architecture and it is staticly linked.

````
$ readelf -A rootfs/bin/busybox 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-M"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6

$ readelf -A linux/vmlinux
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-M"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Microcontroller
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 2
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int

$ cat spec.txt 
dir /dev 755 0 0
nod /dev/console 644 0 0 c 5 1
dir /bin 755 1000 1000
slink /bin/sh busybox 777 0 0
slink /bin/mknod busybox 777 0 0
file /bin/busybox ../rootfs/bin/busybox 755 0 0
dir /proc 755 0 0
dir /sys 755 0 0
dir /mnt 755 0 0
file /init ../rootfs/init 755 0 0```
````

Kernel full boot log:
https://pastebin.com/raw/kG78ksKJ

Kernel .config:
https://pastebin.com/raw/2Dk4w99h

Busybox .config:
https://pastebin.com/raw/KzuFdKFr

Comment: Sorry kernel full boot log URL stop work, here is a new one: https://pastebin.com/raw/kG78ksKJ

Comment: Instead of providing a new, working link on a comment, please just edit your original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kernel cannot execute binaries (error -8)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610094/kernel-cannot-execute-binaries-error-8)